# Google App Engine launcher not starting all of a sudden

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been using GAE for about 2 months now, and so far, the journey has been quite smooth for me. Until today. Today, while the launcher was still on(along with other applications and programs), I had to shut down my PC without closing the existing running programs for some reason. When I restarted my PC, I couldn't launch my GAE application. When I try to force close it, it says that "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe is not responding". This is what opens up when I double click on the launcher icon:

[image: This is what I see]

When I maximize the window for the launcher:

[image]

Is this because my GAE application is now corrupted after I shut down the PC without closing it? Or is it something else? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This looks more like a bug.. Did you try to reinstall?

Comment: Yeah...I tried reinstalling. Same problem. This is really scary now!

Comment: You can always run the dev server using the command line.. I'm not sure what's the problem here..

Comment: Is something wrong with my desktop now? Because I never had this problem before with GAE until today. And this is really scary because all my work now is stalled because of this. I don't know how to deploy my local files now or test them locally without GAE! And no one seems to be having this problem on the net. This is really strange!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out what the problem was. Well, today I had installed two new softwares: Youtube Accelerator and CamStudio. Ever since then, my GAE wasn't starting. So I just uninstalled those two softwares, and now GAE is working again without any hassles! Don't really know why those softwares were causing this problem, but I am more than happy that I have the power of GAE back again!

Comment: In the future.. you can always run and deploy stuff without the Launcher.. but via command line: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver you will just have to put in the PATH (if not already there) the App Engine sources..

Comment: actually I tried that too...but I got an error that 'my_app_name' is not in the directory. I had even downloaded Herokuapp command line, because I had virtually lost hope of ever solving this weird problem. Thankfully GAE is working now. Thanks for all the help! And yeah, any reason why I was getting that error on the dev server?